# Implementing search bar functionality with AJAX and HTTP Requests - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to create a search function that finds data depending on the query that is entered (so a typical search bar in my HTML). I need it to search the title of the books that I have stored in my database which can be accessed in the GET requests location. So far, I have managed the code to get the array from the database, but I am trying to search by title.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

const books_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/books" 

xhttp.open("GET", books_url, true);
xhttp.addEventListener('load', function() {

    function bookSearch() {
        var search = document.getElementById('searchBar').value
        document.getElementById('booksFound').innerHTML = ""
        console.log('Looking for ' + search)
        console.log('Search button works')
    }

    document.getElementById('searchBtn').addEventListener('click', bookSearch, false)
    document.getElementById("divShowBooks").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    console.log(xhttp);
    console.log(this.response);
});
xhttp.send();
```

Here is my **HTML** code where I am working with the search bar and attempting to display it.

```
<section class="bookSearchBar">
    <h4>Search Books</h4>
    <form method="GET" id="searchBooks" class="form-inline md-form form-sm active-pink-2 mt-2">
        <input id="searchBar" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Search by Title" aria-label="Search">
        <button id="searchBtn" type="button">Submit</button>
        <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </form> 
    <div id="booksFound"></div>
</section>
```

Please inform me if you need more information.

UPDATE: Re-posted for hopefully a less confusing title.

Comment: and what is your question then?

Comment: shouldn't you send (`xhttp.send();`) the search term?

Comment: @Jamesonthedog I am not sure what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: @AelaHuntress, well you want to search the term right? so you use a server-side search right? *what* do you search if all you do is `GET` the url as is? how does it know what to search? at the moment your just getting "http://127.0.0.1:3000/books" as is and that's why it doesn't work

Comment: @Jamesonthedog That's exactly why I am asking this question. I do not know how to properly implement this.

Comment: @AelaHuntress well, in that case your question is not enough. it should include the server side part of you code... basically your server-side page should work something like this: "127.0.0.1:3000/books?term=godfather" to search for godfather books right? so, does it work like that?

Comment: Yes it does. All of the server-side code has been done for me. I have been assigned to solely code the front-end and communicate it with the back-end. I am concerned to paste server-side code because a) it is considered confidential information for my project and b) it would be rather long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna assume your search works using `term` as the `GET` variable (i.e a search looks like this:  `http://127.0.0.1:3000/books?term=godfather`)

```
const books_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/books";
document.getElementById('searchBtn').addEventListener('click', bookSearch, false);

function bookSearch() {
    var search = document.getElementById('searchBar').value;
    document.getElementById('booksFound').innerHTML = "";
    console.log('Looking for ' + search);
    console.log('Search button works');
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { // this is what happens when an answer is returned 
        if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) { // a valid answer
           document.getElementById("divShowBooks").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
         }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", books_url, true);
    xhttp.send("term=" + search ); // sending the term variable to the search page
}
```

you should read up on these basic principles, or this is gonna be confusing:

[GET parameters](https://en.ryte.com/wiki/GET_Parameter)

[AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

hope this gets you there - good luck and happy new year!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. However, when I search a term, it instead retrieves the entire array of all the books that are in the database and displays it in the DOM. I am trying to implement this system as an SPA and having everything work dynamically i.e. the search bar filtering the current data that is displayed. So, I actually have no other pages but index.html right now. Programming and accessing the endpoints is where I am indeed getting disorientated.

Comment: well, I can't really get it all done for you since I lack a lot of information you cannot give me... if you can't (or don't know how to) get a filtered list from the server-side part, you could use client-side filtering but you'll need to know more about JavaScript and how the data is returned

Comment: in what language is the server side written? you need to find the parameter name the page is looking for